# How to find a session record in the database using the cookie value in an Rails app using activerecord activerecord-session_store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails app that uses Devise and the [activerecord-session_store](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store) gem with a minimalistic setup (nothing beyond the defaults).

I'm trying to to use the value stored in the cookie to manually find the corresponding session record in the `sessions` table that activerecord-session_store uses.

The problem is that the session value that I get from the cookie does not appear to be stored "as is" in the database and ergo I cannot simply do a find_by to find the record it matches to.

Or in other words:

This is what the cookie value looks like:
a5a879b4f923d2eea7707cf8ce28cd80

and this is what the `session_id` in the `sessions` table looks like:
2::801e4371783f192b4ee95be9def08bf17daaa1ebeed589dbdfeeb8742e2dd9f6

The value in the `sessions` table appears to be somehow encrypted and I cannot find info on how to match the two.

Worth pointing out at the app works normally so it somehow does the matching internally. I'm trying to match the session_id for a different use case.

I have tried using the `find_by_session_id` method that `ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session` exposes in hopes it will do some transformations and magically find the correct session but it appears to be just the standard find_by from active record which does not work since the string values are different.

My guess is that I need to somehow transform the value that comes from the cookie to the format data is kept in the session_id columns and only then do a find_by but I'm not sure how.

Do you have any ideas how I could find the correct session using the cookie value? Thanks

Comment: Your cookie is not a session id. Rails keeps everything regarding sessions and other cookie-based things encrypted. So it decrypts cookie every time, and than it gets `session_id` out of it. It uses secret_key_base to encrypt data

Comment: Appreciate your comment but I believe you're wrong - believe you're describing the default way Rails works BUT with activerecord-session_store the "data" part of the cookie is kept in the database and the browser only keeps a reference to the record in the database. My problem is how to fetch that database record using the ID that's kept in the cookie.

Comment: I may be encrypted anyway, please, check it. Try `session.id` inside your controller and see if it coincide with cookie value, or not.

Comment: Yes, I tried that - session.id returns the same value as the content of the cookie. The problem is how to map that value to a record in the sessions table. Appreciate your ideas, Nick!

Comment: Did you set any [configs](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store#configuration)? Can you post your migration file for the gem?

Comment: Is there a chance you're hitting [this known bug](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store/issues/172)?

Comment: appreciate everyone's help! Just posted the solution that came to. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I can't provide details about how and why this works, I figured out a solution:

First, a private_session_id needs to be generated from the value from the cookie value and only then a `find_by_session_id` can be called.

Something like this:

`private_session_id = Rack::Session::SessionId.new(COOKIE_VALUE).private_id`
`ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.find_by_session_id(private_session_id)`

Comment: FYI,  I'm not using activerecord-session_store gem but Redis. Here is how to find the session :

```ruby
Marshal.load(Rails.cache.redis.get(redis_key)).value
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to contribute a bit more to the previous answer because I was curious about this question myself.

For more details, head over to the [activerecord-session_store](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store/blob/master/lib/active_record/session_store.rb) gem source where you'll find the `Rack::Session::SessionId` class that handles what we're discussing.

To make it work, you need to pass the `public_id` obtained from the cookie during object initialization. Inside the class, there's a constant `ID_VERSION` set to 2.

The private method `hash_sid` takes a string as input and returns a 64-character hex value:

```
def hash_sid(sid)
  Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(sid)
end
```

And then, there's a method called `private_id` that gives you a string matching the `session_id` stored in your database record:

```
def private_id
  "#{ID_VERSION}::#{hash_sid(public_id)}"
end
```

You can use either of the following queries depending on your implementation:

```
ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.find_by_session_id(private_id)
```

or

```
Session.find_by(session_id: private_id)
```